# Stripe Tokenisation Timeout with Apple Pay

Tags: ios, swift, stripe-payments, applepay

I'm following the tutorial [here](https://stripe.com/docs/apple-pay) to integrate Apple Pay in a native swift app. I've completed all the steps and am currently attempting to test on a physical device.

Unfortunately the payment fails after a long wait, looking at the network traffic it looks like https://api/stripe.com/v1/tokens is timing out, Please find my code for creating an Apple Pay context below (empty strings are sensitive info that I don't want to share but are usually populated);

```
private func makePayment() {
    let merchantIdentifier = ""
    let paymentRequest = Stripe.StripeAPI.paymentRequest(withMerchantIdentifier: merchantIdentifier, country: "GB", currency: "GBP")
    
    paymentRequest.paymentSummaryItems = [
        PKPaymentSummaryItem(label: "Payment", amount: amount),
        PKPaymentSummaryItem(label: "Service Charge", amount: 0.05),
        PKPaymentSummaryItem(label: "", amount: NSDecimalNumber(value: amount.doubleValue + 0.05))
    ]
    
    guard let context = STPApplePayContext(paymentRequest: paymentRequest, delegate: self) else { return }
    context.presentApplePay(completion: nil)
}
```

I have recreated the merchant ID and certificate etc. and made sure the merchant identifier matches the one on stripe.

Comment: the /v1/tokens timeout might signify that your mobile app can't reach Stripe or a different networking issue. Can your mobile app make a non-Apple Pay /v1/tokens request? Try calling `createToken()` with some sample 4242 test card params and see if that works. If your merchant ID and certificate were off, the /v1/tokens request would 400, not time out

Comment: Good suggestion, will try shortly.